# Basilisk II error

Tags: emulation, apple-macintosh

When I try to open the BasiliskIIGUI.exe I get errors saying things like 'The program can't start because libglib 2.0-0.dll is missing from your computer'

I have the recommended GTK installed and I have everything required in the setup guide. I am on Windows 10 x64

Comment: If you are the same Jordan Barron as has asked a couple of other questions, the accounts can be merged.  If you wish this to happen, raise a custom flag.

Comment: [glib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) is one of the low level libraries needed by GTK, so very likely your GTK installation is not complete.

Comment: If you can't yet flag with this account, feel free to `@` `Chenmunka` or `@wizzwizz4` to let us know if the other accounts also belong to you. (Note that there's no penalty to having loads of questions on the same account.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that many programs requiring glib on Windows don't always find the installation directory that GTK installs to. I'm not sure if it is the GTK installer or the individual programs themselves; haven't looked at this in a while.

While you could update your `PATH` at the system level to include that directory, you could also cheat and just copy it to the directory where Basilisk II's `.exe` is residing.